# How to demonstrate this set defines a topology without using compacity?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let X be a Hausdorff topological space. Let $\left\{w\right\}$ **not** be a subset of X. Let's define the Alexander compactification to be $C=X\cup \left\{w\right\}$.

A natural topology defined on this space is the set of all open set of $T_X$, the topology of X , combined with all the set of the form $K^C\bigcup \left\{w\right\} $ , with K a compact of X.

I want to demonstrate this is well defined.
During the natural demonstration of it , i get to the point :

$\bigcup_{i\in I} (K_i^C\cup \left\{w \right\})=\bigcup_{i\in I} K_i^C\cup \left\{w \right\}=(\bigcap K_i)^C \bigcup \left\{w \right\}$. (This point is to show opened set from the second type remains open set of the second type.)

what a author i read writes is , $\bigcap K_i$ is closed as intersection of closed set , and the ambiant space is compact , so it's a compact. But i can't use this argument as i'm defining the topology here !
How can i deal with this problem ?

Also have to show the finite intersection of type 2 open set remains of type 2

$$ \bigcap(K_i^C \cup \left\{w \right\})=(\bigcup K_i)^C\cup \left\{w \right\} $$
So the problem is also that i would need a space tha contains $\bigcup K_i$ and is compact i guess

Comment: You can view the intersection as a subset of one of the compact $K_i$.

Comment: But compact would not be defined if my topology doesn't exist yet. Maybe you mean $T_X$ compact but i'd need to show $T_X$ compact implies $T_C$ compact.

Comment: In order to prove that the set $(\bigcap K_i)^C \bigcup \left\{w \right\}$ remains an open set of $C$ of the second type, by definition of the "second type" what you have to prove is that $\bigcap K_i$ is a compact set of $X$. The proof that $\bigcap K_i$ is a compact set of $X$ is carried out in the given topology on $X$, using the argument suggested by @user2271513.

Comment: oh yes totally , i agree now. is there a solution for the union problem ?

Comment: the fact it's finite union would give me a finite T_x-open cover for each T_X open cover maybe

Comment: Yes, a finite union of compact sets is compact

Answer (score 1):

The compact sets we’re talking about are subsets of $X$, which is a given Hausdorff space. So there is no problem: the open sets of $X$ are given and hence so are the compact subsets.

And the intersection of the compact (and thus closed) subsets is closed inside any of the compact sets of that intersection and compactness is intrinsic. So that intersection is also compact.

For a finite intersection of that type we can use that a *finite* union of compact sets is compact ( easy to see by using the cover definition).